# Why don't locale variables show up in the output of env or printenv?

Tags: environment-variables, locale

The `locale` command prints a list of environmental variables containing info related to the users locale:

```
$locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Why don't I see these variables when I run `printenv` or `env`?

Comment: Do they appear if you do `grep LANG /proc/self/environ` (or any of LC_ listed)?

Comment: Nope, no LC, no LANG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `locale` command **does not** print environment variables.  It prints the state of the user's locale, whether set by environment or by inference.

For example, if `LC_TIME` is not set, its value is taken from `LANG`.  And if `LC_ALL` is set, all other settings are overriden.

Try it:

```
$ LANG=ja_JP.utf8 locale
LANG=ja_JP.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_ALL=

$ LANG=ja_JP.utf8 LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8 locale
LANG=ja_JP.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.utf8"
LC_ALL=

$ LANG=ja_JP.utf8 LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_ALL=POSIX locale
LANG=ja_JP.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=POSIX
```

You will observe that computed values are shown in double quotes and those that are explicitly set by environment variables are unquoted.